# Is this a valid proof that $g^{|G|}=e$ for $g \in G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $e$ be its identity element, $g \in G$, and $o(g)$ be the order of $g$.

My textbook gives the proof that $g^{|G|}=g^{(o(g)*|G|/o(g))}=(g^{o(g)})^{|G|/o(g)}=e^{|G|/o(g)}=e$.

However, is this on its own a valid proof? It seems to me that it relies on $\frac{|G|}{o(g)}$ being an integer, which, unless I'm missing something, is not a trivial assumption (if it were not an integer then $e^{|G|/o(g)}$ would not be defined, correct?).

Am I correct in thinking this proof is not a valid one? And if so, how could one complete it by proving that $|G|/o(g)$ is an integer?

Comment: $\mid G\mid$ is finite?

Answer (score 5):

The subgroup generated by $g$ has exactly $o(g)$ elements; by Lagrange's theorem the order of the subgroup must divide the order of the group.